# Touchmove event triggering twice only iOS Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, touchmove

i need help about this. Alert trigger'in twice in one move

`$(window).bind('touchmove', function(e) { alert('something'); });`

Comment: I mean, a touch can quickly result in two events as it's a pretty... inaccurate way of input. The question is if `touchstart` or `touchend` triggers twice, which I doubt. Touchmoves get triggered multiple times while a user is moving their finger.

Comment: I disagree with this, shouldn't it trigger an alert once every touchmove move? To get the alert, I have to tap again. like this on android

Comment: Input events don’t hold to rendering timings and can be fired multiple times at the same time. Better yet: don’t tie alerts to move events, and use the appropriate event instead. The ones guaranteed to happen once. Like start and end, or down and up.